# Issue with Dapper connection: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows, dapper

I am trying to use Dapper to execute quires within a Microsoft SQL Server. The code I am using is the following:

```
public void Insert_Cycle(int cylinderId, int cycleNumber, float cycleMaxPressure, float cyleMinPressure, DateTime cycleStartTime, DateTime cyleEndTime)
{
    using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB Name"].ConnectionString))
    {
        Models.T6Testing newcycle = new Models.T6Testing { CylinderId = cylinderId, CycleNumber = cycleNumber, CycleMaxPressure = cycleMaxPressure, CyleMinPressure = cyleMinPressure, CycleStartTime = cycleStartTime, CyleEndTime = cyleEndTime };
        List<Models.T6Testing> cycles = new List<Models.T6Testing>();
        cycles.Add(new Models.T6Testing { CylinderId = cylinderId, CycleNumber = cycleNumber, CycleMaxPressure = cycleMaxPressure, CyleMinPressure = cyleMinPressure, CycleStartTime = cycleStartTime, CyleEndTime = cyleEndTime });
        db.Execute("dbo.SP_INSERT_CYCLE @Cylinder_ID,@Cycle_number,@Cycle_max_pressure,@Cycle_min_pressure,@Cycle_start_time,@Cycle_end_time", cycles);
    }
}
```

The connection string is in the following format:

```
<connectionStrings>  
    <add name="DB Name"
         connectionString="Data Source=x.x.x.x,#port;Initial Catalog=Database Name;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=xxxxxx"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

In order to test if the Connection String is in the right format I have used vttestconnectionstring from https://www.vadimtabakman.com/connection-string-tester.aspx, and I was able to run queries with it. Could someone point me in the right direction where I am making a mistake?

Comment: You have too many commas in your `Data Source` connection string option.

Comment: So it works on one machine but not another machine. Is that the problem? Is the firewall open for the right ports? Both outgoing and incoming.

Comment: There's almost certainly a problem in your connection string, but we can't tell when you've provided an obfuscated one, instead of the one you're actually using (minus the pasword).

Comment: Use SQL Server Management Studio and look at login window.  The server has a name and instance which need to be in the connection string.  Then see if Window Credentials is used.  If so do not put the User Name and Password into the connection string.  Instead use Integrated Security=true;  Then the user credentials are used.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger Sorry, my mistake, it was suppose to be dots.

Comment: @rene I am using the same machine, sql ssms and the test program can connect, while my program cannot.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger This is the string that I am using, other than the IP address, the database name, and the password that is complete in the "real" one.

Comment: @jdweng I am using SQL server authentication.

Comment: Try removing the `#` in front of the port number.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger I have tried it, unfortunately I still receive the same error.

Comment: Are you connecting to a local Server or a Server on a remote machine?  If you connecting on a remote machine I do not think windows will allow the remote connection with a username and password.

Comment: @jdweng I am connecting to a remote server, which runs SQL Server 2019 in a Docker container. In that case, why can I connect with other applications, or with Visual Studio's SQL Server Object Explorer for example?

Comment: Are you connecting in other applications with username/password?  Same user Account?  Same database?  With SQL Client or Entity?  I usually start debugging using SQL Server Management Studio and get SSMS working before I try to connect in software.

Comment: @jdweng I am using the exact same database and user&password. SSMS also works just fine.

Comment: Not sure why you have port number in connection string if you are using the standard port number of SQL Server.  The name and instance of the database in the connection string must be same as login window of SSMS.  Can you query with SSMS the same Initial Database?  Just because you can connect to Server with SSMS doesn't mean you can read a database.  Each database on the server can have different credentials.  So SSMS can connect but not be able to do a query.

Comment: @jdweng Your previous comment about windows blocking me have made me to add the funtion to a new WPF application, and it does work there. So the issue is somewhere with the UWP project iteself. I will be looking into now, what changes I have to do in my main project. Thank you for the idea!!

Comment: Are you using a Network Credential in the WPF?  I believe the Window firewall blocks normal username/password.  So you have to use a Network Credential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax and the connection string was correct. The issue was with the UWP project, where Internet was not added to capabilities in Package.appxmanifest